# How would I add existing folders to a project in Eclipse?

Tags: open-source, eclipse

I don't know how to add the [this](http://code.google.com/p/rokon/downloads/detail?name=rokon_src_2-0-3.zip&can=2&q=) into my existing project.

The only thing I learned so far was adding jar files, not those types of folders.  How would I add the source to my project?  Are they packages?

Steps I've done:

1. Download
2. Extract into a separate folder

I think I might be over thinking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpret the download link right, you are downloading the sources of a lib.

If you are not already using that library, you should download [this](https://code.google.com/p/rokon/downloads/detail?name=rokon_lib_2-0-3.zip) instead and add it to the project's build path. Copy it to your folder, where you have your other libs placed and add it via right click menu **Build Path** **-->** **Add to Build Path**. Afterwards you can use the classes from that library.

If you already have that lib in your project, I guess you want to attach the sources to the lib. Therefore you need to go into your project's build path and edit the jar, and configure there, where the zip file (which does not need to be extracted) with the sources is. There is a detailed description for linking sources to jar files in the [eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm).

For further details on build path configuration you could read [in the eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm).

Comment: I added the jar file but i couldn't find the source.  Is it the [link](https://code.google.com/p/rokon/downloads/detail?name=rokon_src_2-0-3.zip&can=2&q=) I posted earlier?  If it is, how would I put to my jar file after I add it to the libs folder of my project?

Comment: Yes, that is what I described in my third paragraph.

Comment: I'm confused.  I use https://code.google.com/p/rokon/downloads/detail?name=rokon_src_2-0-3.zip&can=2&q=, extract it.  Then I insert it to the libs folder?  Then I use java build path and add it to the source attachment?  The folders aren't in jar files, they are formatted similar to src that contains all the java files

Comment: There is no need to extract the downloaded file, you could put it into the same folder as the jar file. You can directly link it as the sources of the rokon.jar.

Comment: Well I did that to the file but i still got errors on the project.  Most of the errors were about things unresolved type and undefined methods.  I got the direct source from code.google.com but there are still errors!  I was thinking it was the jar file, but now I'm clueless.  Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: This depends on the concrete errors and maybe if the rokon jar has other dependencies.